# How to create horizontally spanning cells with Bixby Views?

Tags: bixby

I want to create cells that span horizontally in the Bixby view. Previously, we were able to do this with a .bml file. The Weather Channel app currently does this with a large chart with corresponding data below the points. Below is an example the app UI I want to create.

[image: app screenshot]

I tried creating several `vbox` elements and adding a `layout-macro` inside, but the `vbox` won't take that type of element. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a workaround with `single-line`. To create a view like this, use the typical `hbox`-`vbox` model, and do this for each `vbox`:

```
vbox {
  content {

    single-line {
      text {
        value {
          template ("#{value(data.hourly[i].hour)}")
        }
        style (Title_XS)
      }
    }

    single-line {
      image {
        style (Title_L)
        url ("#{value(data.hourly[i].image)}")
      }
    }

    single-line {
      spacer
      text { 
        value {
          template ("#{value(data.hourly[i].temperature)}")
        }
        style (Title_S)
      }
    }

  }
}
```

**Result**

[image: Bixby Screenshot]